# bootstrap card body button spans across the screen how to set a width wrap content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

code in handlebars

```
<h1>Ideas</h1>

{{#each ideas}}
    <div class="card card-body mb-2">
        <h4 class="card-title">{{title}}</h4>
        <p class="card-text">{{detail}}</p>
        <small>{{id}}</small>
        <a href="/ideas/edit/{{id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
    </div>
{{else}}
no ideas found
{{/each}}
```

you can see the image link below
[image: card button spans 100% want it to wrap content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUfEX.png)

Answer (score 1):

Here the card for bootstrap working totally fine

https://jsfiddle.net/8c8y5qf6/1

I would say as i saw from your picture that you should give for the class
`.btn.btn-primary { display: inline-block }` and it should be already **inline-block as default** to not span full width as i see the card take the full width it might be all the children inside taken **display block or display flex** for all the children gives it this styling for example that show how the button looks

```css
.card--inline .btn {
    display: inline-block;
}

.card--flex .btn {
   display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card card--inline">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>


<div class="card card--flex">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8c8y5qf6/1